# stored procedure with a parameter

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

i need to create a simple stored procedure in postgres with just one parameter Site ID,
Stored Proc should take site id as an input and return the data from a table  for that site id
select * from finance.facility_d where site_id = 'parameter'

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE.

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION facility(text) RETURNS SETOF finc.gpr_facility_d AS $$
    SELECT * FROM finc.gpr_facility_d WHERE site_id = $1;
   $$ LANGUAGE SQL;    I am not sure where i can pass values after executing the above, please help

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM  facility(some_id);``` will return the values from the query. Not sure what you mean by pass values though.

Comment: is it possible to write a  procedure for the same requirement?

Comment: If you are talking about ```CREATE PROCEDURE``` , procedures cannot  ```RETURN``` anything. You can use ```INOUT``` to output, but then you have to specify each value. The function you created is the simplest solution. Not sure why you would want to use a ```PROCEDURE```?

Comment: If you want to return something, use a function, not a procedure